# Check if Android Media Player can play a file

Tags: java, android

In Android, is there a way to check if a given file is a legitimate file for the media player? This is my current method of testing if a file is playable or not in a media player.

```
public boolean isPlayable(File file){
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(this, uri);
        player.reset();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid File: " + file.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm using the exception to test, basically if it throws an exception then something is up and we shouldn't play the file. To me, this doesn't seem very clean even though it seems to do the job just fine. Is there a better way I should be looking at this problem? I just want to know if a file is going to throw an exception before I try to plug it into a media player.