# android mediaplayer url not found

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have some mp3 file in my web server.
I have to use in my app.
My mp3 on server might increase or decrease.(teacher would upload new file or delete old file
My mp3 name is T1.mp3, T2.mp3, T3.mp3, etc.
I have a next button,I hope when mp3 file not found,it would show it is last one.
EX: I am in T40.mp3 I click next to go to T41.mp3, but T41 was delete by teacher,
So, I would show this file not found.
I try it but it can not show and will be shutdown...
how can I do?
this is my code:

```
private ImageView.OnClickListener nextbtn=new ImageView.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String tmp=url;   //url=www.XXX......
        T++;
        tmp+="/"+filename[T]; //filename is number ex:T21.mp3
        try {
            totalTime=0;
            mediaplayer.reset();
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(tmp);

            mediaplayer.prepare();
            totalTime=mediaplayer.getDuration();

            if(mediaplayer.getDuration()==0){
                //show that mp3 is not found
                mytoast("not found");
            }
            else{
                totalTime=mediaplayer.getDuration();
            }
            mediaplayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) { }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
};
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the 2 empty catch blocks with

```
catch (Throwable e) {
    mytoast("not found"); // or something else happened
}
```

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513579/check-if-android-media-player-can-play-a-file), it by itself provides a method to check if a file is playable.

Comment: I have use your code but it still not show "not found"